# Do you commit a complete web-directory to SVN or you do some exceptions (large binaries)?

Tags: svn, version-control, video

Particularly I mean videos.

I have fair bit of videos on my website and as I do submit all graphics with the sources, I have serious doubts about committing videos and archives (sizes between 10MB and 300MB).

Does it make any sense at all to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current project is an ASP.Net MVC application that uses multiple third part assemblies which I have placed in svn so that a developer can get the latest at anytime and will have all the build scripts and libraries along with the code that they need to build the application. The dlls are placed in a lib folder and all the visual studio projects can then access these based on a relative path. The advantage is that when tagging our code all dependant libraries also exist with the code that uses them so if I need to roll back to a previous release that uses an older version of a library that I've since updated I'll still get the correct version. I think this works well for developer related files that are needed to build the application so that automated builds and continuous integration can be easily used. This has also worked we for me working in a distributed team on this projects.

However I do feel that files such as video and anything that's 300MB in size is impractical to add to any version control system. On some projects I've worked on in the past there has been a server used to hold all media files and these are then copied to the test and production environments as part of an automated script.

Answer (score 2):

SVN is all about sources. It's not a place for content or binaries in most cases, so such files shouldn't be usually passed to SVN.
But I will probably put it in SVN if it's  some hard to reproduce test data used buy all developers.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you don't want to keep track of changes you make to videos, so I'd try to find some other place for them.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix ***Version*** Control System and some kind of ***Content*** Management System.

You need to link some videos or archives to a certain state of your VCS-managed sources, but I doubt one given video ends up having several *versions* of itself.
If those binaries do not evolve in time (or very rarely), a VCS is *not* the right repository for them.
For instance, a Maven repo (which can record any type of artifact) can work fairly well combined with a SVN repo.